# Docker / AWS Configure on server side / no basic auth credentials

Tags: docker, amazon-ecr

I have successfully send my images to AWS ECR
(so I did the `aws configure` in my windows local computer)

Now I am trying to start de `docker-compose` from the linux server

I followed the same `aws configure` process

But When I start docker-compose *I got this error :

```
ERROR: Head "https://914357740529.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/my-app/manifests/1.0": no basic auth credentials
```

I tried also to include this line (coming from the **Push commands for myapp** ) though I thought I was needed this just to push my image to to ECR

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-3 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 914357740529.dkr.ecr.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com
```

And the result on linux is also :

```
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

What could be the cause ? Would it be possible that there is a problem with the region ?

Thanks